# Array empty after XML Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I'm a beginner in Xcode, and I have tried to create an app that downloads an XML file, parses it and adds every obtained element in an array. This array is then used by a Table View to create new rows. Unfortunately it didn't work. After NSLogging nearly every single step, I noticed that the app downloads and parses the files, but when it comes to adding the data to the array, the app empties the array and fills it again with the last element, as many times as there were elements in the beginning. Even like that, the Table View should have got some rows, but when I get out of the parsing routine, it seems that the array is filled with only "\n", which I don't understand. I do allocate and initialize the array properly:
    `myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`
And I add objects to the array with:
    `[myArray addObject:@"Hello"];`

I precise that I use Xcode 4.6.2. for iOS 6, and that I am a beginner (please don't shoot me ;) )

Thanks for your help!

The XML File I use can be found on ilgl.lgl.lu/Missings_Data/Missings_Data.xml

Here parts of the code I use:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:  (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Released_classes"]) {
    prof = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    classe = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    span = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    service = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Data containers initialized");
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
// ignore root and empty elements
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Missing_Class"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Released_classes"]) return;
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Classe"]) {
    [classe addObject:currentElement];
    NSLog(@"Added element to Classe: %@", currentElement);
    NSLog(@"Elements in class: %@", classe);
    return;
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Professeur"]) {
    [prof addObject:currentElement];
    NSLog(@"Added element to Prof: %@", currentElement);
    NSLog(@"Elements in prof: %@", classe);
    return;
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Lecon_libérée"]) {
    [span addObject:currentElement];
    NSLog(@"Added element to Span: %@", currentElement);
    NSLog(@"Elements in span: %@", classe);
    return;
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Service"]) {
    [service addObject:currentElement];
    NSLog(@"Added element to Service: %@", currentElement);
    NSLog(@"Elements in service: %@", classe);
    return;
}
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
[currentElement setString:string];
}

#pragma mark - Table View Data Organization

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
 // Return the number of sections.
 NSLog(@"Number of sections: predefined 1");
 return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 // Return the number of rows in the section.
 NSLog(@"Number of rows: %i", [classe count]);
 return [classe count];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 }
 NSString *cellText = [classe objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
 NSLog(@"Cell being created: %@", cellText);
 return cell;
 }
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to Wain, I added `currentElement = nil` before the end of every `if` condition in `parser:didEndElement:`and the verification he gave me. It now works perfectly! Thanks to all those who tried to help :)

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: Could we have a sample of the downloaded files?

Comment: For the XMLParser code, I used the one given by Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing `currentElement` all the time and updating the value. Every time you update the value you overwrite the old value - everywhere you previously stored it (it's the same object in all the arrays).

At the end of `parser:didEndElement:` you want to set `currentElement = nil;`. Then, in `parser:foundCharacters:` you want a check:

```
if (currentElement == nil) {
    currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
} else {
    [currentElement appendString:string];
}
```

Comment: It fixed my issues. Thank you very much, I had been breakin my head on that all day! :)